# Changing for in loop to for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, for-in-loop

Imagine I have an object called projects. The projects object has a key called projects that is an **array** of 2 other objects. Each one of the other 2 objects has an array of images. I was able to iterate through each image in the array of each object using for in loops but I want to use for loops or forEach instead. What can I do? Here is my code:

```js
var projects = {};

projects.projects = [
{
"title": "mycode",
"dates": "mycode",
"description": "mycode",
"images": ["http://lorempixel.com/400/200/", "http://lorempixel.com/350/150/", "http://lorempixel.com/500/300/"]
},

{
"title": "mycode",
"dates": "mycode",
"description": "mycode",
"images": ["http://lorempixel.com/400/200/", "http://lorempixel.com/350/150/", "http://lorempixel.com/500/300/"]
}

];

projects.display = function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < projects.projects.length; i++) {
        
        var formattedProjectTitle = HTMLprojectTitle.replace("%data%", projects.projects[i].title);
        $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectTitle);

        var formattedProjectDates = HTMLprojectDates.replace("%data%", projects.projects[i].dates);
        $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectDates);

        var formattedProjectDescription = HTMLprojectDescription.replace("%data%", projects.projects[i].description);
        $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectDescription);
        
        //Iterate through each image in the projects objects.

        for (image in projects.projects[i].images) {
            var formattedProjectImages = HTMLprojectImage.replace("%data%", projects.projects[i].images[image]);
            $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectImages);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `projects.projects.forEach(function(project, index, projects) {
 console.log(project.title);
 project.images.forEach(function(image, index, images) {
      console.log(image)
    })
})` ??

Comment: thanks but I need to change the loop iterating the image only not the outer loop.

Comment: like `for (var i = 0; i < projects.projects.length; i++) {
 projects.projects[i].images.forEach(function(image) {
      console.log(image)
    })
}` ?

Comment: yes but would you please fit my code instead of console.log(image) ?

When I add my code inside the function scope, it breaks the image and points to undefined. 

Here is what I exactly wrote:

projects.projects[i].images.forEach(function(image) {
            var formattedProjectImages = HTMLprojectImage.replace("%data%", projects.projects[i].images[image]);
            $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectImages);

Comment: I put it in an answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use nested for loops to do exactly that

```
for (var i = 0; i < projects.projects.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < projects.projects[i].images.length; j++) {
       var x = projects.projects[i].images[j];
       console.log(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems you also forget to add the j < projects.projects[i].images.length; but it works now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `forEach` version of the loop, which I would prefer to reduce the length of names used.

```
projects.projects.forEach(function(project) {
    var formattedProjectTitle = HTMLprojectTitle.replace("%data%", project.title);
    $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectTitle);

    var formattedProjectDates = HTMLprojectDates.replace("%data%", project.dates);
    $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectDates);

    var formattedProjectDescription = HTMLprojectDescription.replace("%data%", project.description);
    $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectDescription);

    project.images.forEach(function(image) {
        var formattedProjectImages = HTMLprojectImage.replace("%data%", image);
        $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectImages);
    });
});

// Alternatively, if you have the browser support, for..of will work as well. 
// I use let instead of var as let is block scoped rather than function scoped (Again, check browser support)

for (let project of projects.projects) {
    let formattedProjectTitle = HTMLprojectTitle.replace("%data%", project.title);
    $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectTitle);

    let formattedProjectDates = HTMLprojectDates.replace("%data%", project.dates);
    $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectDates);

    let formattedProjectDescription = HTMLprojectDescription.replace("%data%", project.description);
    $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectDescription);

    for (let image of project.images) {
        let formattedProjectImages = HTMLprojectImage.replace("%data%", image);
        $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectImages);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a `for` loop and worrying about indexes and off-by-1 errors, you can nest two `forEach` loops:

```
projects.projects.forEach(project => {
  var formattedProjectTitle = HTMLprojectTitle.replace("%data%", project.title);

  // ...

  project.images.forEach(image => {
    var formattedProjectImages = HTMLprojectImage.replace("%data%", image);
    $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectImages);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you alot but what is the =>? I am still new to the language.

Comment: It is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). `project => { return 'stuff'; }` is the same as `function (project) { return 'stuff'; }`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var projects = {};

projects.projects = [{
  "title": "mycode",
  "dates": "mycode",
  "description": "mycode",
  "images": ["http://lorempixel.com/400/200/",     "http://lorempixel.com/350/150/",     "http://lorempixel.com/500/300/"]
}, {
  "title": "mycode",
  "dates": "mycode",
  "description": "mycode",
  "images": ["http://lorempixel.com/400/200/", "http://lorempixel.com/350/150/", "http://lorempixel.com/500/300/"]
}];

projects.display = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < projects.projects.length; i++) {
        var formattedProjectTitle = HTMLprojectTitle.replace("%data%", projects.projects[i].title);
        $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectTitle);

        var formattedProjectDates = HTMLprojectDates.replace("%data%", projects.projects[i].dates);
        $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectDates);

        var formattedProjectDescription = HTMLprojectDescription.replace("%data%", projects.projects[i].description);
        $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectDescription);
        
        //Iterate through each image in the projects objects.

        projects.projects[i].images.forEach(function(image) {
          var formattedProjectImages = HTMLprojectImage.replace("%data%", image);
          $(".project-entry:last").append(formattedProjectImages);
        });
    }
}
```